# Where did this probability expression come from?

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

I saw the following steps written where $H$ is a discrete random variable that can take on values $\in \{0,1\}$ and $Q$ is a continuous random variable drawn from the uniform distribution $[0, 1]$:

$$
P(H=1 \ \cap \ Q \leq q)        
$$
Now imagine 
$$
P(H=1 \ \cap \ Q \leq q | Q = v ) \ \ \text{where }v\in [0, q]
$$
Then we can write the following:
$$
P(H = 1 \ \cap \ Q \leq q ) = \int_0^p P(H=1 \ \cap \ Q \leq q | Q = v) f(v) dv \\
$$
and we know
$$
P(H = 1 \ \cap \ Q \leq q | Q = v) = P(H = 1 | Q = v)
$$

Are these steps correct? If so, the logic is not clear to me. I do not understand how the expressions in the last 2 lines are valid. The first expression with the integral came from the law of total probability for a continuous variable, Q, however, why are we able to condition it over $Q=v$? For the last expression, how are we able to remove the $\cap \ Q\leq q$? from the LHS?

Comment: Observe that $\{Q=v\}\subseteq\{Q\leq q\}$. And more generally if $C\subseteq B$ then: $$P(A\cap B\mid C)P(C)=P(A\cap B\cap C)=P(A\cap C)=P(A\mid C)P(C)$$ pointing in the direction of: $$P(A\cap B\mid C)=P(A\mid C)$$

Comment: @drhab Makes sense. So I believe this was in response to the last expression? I think I'm still not sure how the expression inside the integrand is valid. In particular, why are we able to condition it over $Q=v$?

Comment: @drhab My thought originally is to use $P(H = 1 \ \cap \ Q\leq q) = \int_0^q P(H=1 | Q \leq q) P(Q\leq q) = \int_0^q P(H=1 | Q \leq q) f(q') dq'$. It would seem that I'd need to somehow substitute $v$ for $Q\leq q$ to get the expression in the OP.